# Jupyter Notebook and Lab not working in Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've been using Anaconda for a year now and never had a problem. Now, neither Jupyter Lab and Notebook open from it, I have to use Terminal and it's awful. I reinstalled both Anaconda and Jupyter and nothing solved. I tried changing the direction of my workspace and it didn't work. It says that port 8888 is not available and changes to another port, but works through Terminal. Couldn't find anything around the web, not even here that solved my problem. I use Windows 10.

Comment: Have you run the netstat command to see what ports are in use?

Comment: You may not like this answer, but it comes from experience.  Anaconda promotes itself as the official package manager for Python, Jupyter, Jupyter Lab, etc....  But Anaconda is not.  Anaconda puts a huge layer of unknown between users and the actual software.  People are trying to become experts at solving Anaconda issues rather that learning the critically important information about installing software and packages  themselves.  It's far easier to get real answers to specific Python or Jupyter questions than it is to getting answers for Anaconda issues which nobody can ever answer.

Comment: I managed to make my way with Jupyter, I gave up on Anaconda. It's too much to bother. Thanks anyway.